# Twitter reverse auth get full name

Tags: ios, twitter, ios6, single-sign-on

I'm following https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample for implementing reverse SSO in Twitter to my app.
As a result I get `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret`, `user_id` and `screen_name`. Is there any way to get also full user name (`name`) of user?
Thanks in advance.

For some reason I can't find it in the ACAccount properties for `fullName` key. It used to be stored there, but right after reverse auth it is empty. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that `fullName` key exists if user not only added the twitter account, but looked up for details. Otherwise this field is empty. Might help someone.